# Document unregistered trademark?

Tags: united-states, trademark

I've created a company, and I am using unregistered trademarks in my documentation (and soon, products). I've already checked the USPTO and these words are not already trademarked. I am using the (tm) mark after them.

Q: How should I document that I am using these, and when I started using them?

Comment: Are you asking how to register a trademark?

Comment: No.  Unregistered Trademarks have the (tm) mark instead of the (r). If someone else tries to use my unregistered trademark, I need to show that I have been using it, with proof of first use.